# Creating amazon ec2 windows AMIs using amazon sdk in java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am writing an application which would enable my company's future clients to be able to launch Amazon aws instances with Windows OS. Hence, I would want to create windows AMIs first. The article below gives a step by step approach for creating EBS-backed windows AMIs using Amazon AWS console.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_EBSbacked_WinAMI.html

But when I tried looking up the methods provided by **CreateImageRequest** API provided by Amazon SDK, I couldn't quite figure out how to replicate the AWS management console process for creating a windows image in Java. I exhausted my google searches and I came up empty. Has anyone tried this? Is this even possible at all to create Windows images through Amazon SDK?

I found that **CreateInstanceRequest** API has an option to specify the OS types but the options are limited to Amazon Linux or Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The documentation for **CreateInstanceRequest** is below:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/opsworks/model/CreateInstanceRequest.html

I would appreciate any useful link or code snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you are trying to achieve.

Do you want to start an instance in EC2 or with OpsWorks because your second link points to the OpsWorks documentation.

OpsWorks dosen't support Windows right now.